# I am having a value error in my keras model, calling 'model.fit' gives a value error. i keep getting value error error when i try to fit the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, model, tf.keras

```
X=np.array([-7.0,-4.0,-1.0,2.0,5.0,8.0,11.0,14.0])
y=np.array([3.0,6.0,9.0,12.0,15.0,18.0,21.0,24.0])
X=tf.cast(tf.constant(X), dtype=tf.float32)
y=tf.cast(tf.constant(y), dtype=tf.float32)


tf.random.set_seed(42)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
          optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
          metrics=["mae"])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=5)
```

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
10               metrics=["mae"])
11 # 3. Fit the model
---> 12 model.fit(X, y, epochs=5)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
13                 try:
14                     do_return = True

i keep getting this error when i try to fit the model. i am following a youtube video, and i did the exact thing the tutor did , whilst he didn`t get an error, i am getting one. how do i resolve this`

Answer (score 0):

```
X=np.array([-7.0,-4.0,-1.0,2.0,5.0,8.0,11.0,14.0])
y=np.array([3.0,6.0,9.0,12.0,15.0,18.0,21.0,24.0])
X=tf.cast(tf.constant(X), dtype=tf.float32)
y=tf.cast(tf.constant(y), dtype=tf.float32)


tf.random.set_seed(42)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[1])
])
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
      metrics=["mae"])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=5)
```

putting the input_shape=[1], gives your tensor a shape of 1, which makes it able to fit to the model